# Catch event on the Flash particular file close

Tags: c#

I want to keep watch until the myfile.fla close not the Flash.exe
ie
I want to wait till the myfile.fla close not the Flash.exe
ie
How can I catch event of myfile.fla close not the Flash.exe
In c#

```
' Open the notepad application
        info.FileName = "Flash.exe"

        ' Pass a text file name so that notepad will open it
        info.Arguments = "c:\MyFile.fla"
        process.StartInfo = info

        ' Start the process (notepad)
        process.Start()
```

Comment: Your question makes little sense. When using notepad, closing a file is much the same as closing notepad; unless you open another file in the same notepad instance, which will close whatever file was open previously - but that event cannot (reasonably) be "caught" from outside of notepad itself. You might be better off asking what you are trying to achieve (and not how).

Comment: Do you want to detect file changes? If so, check [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

Comment: yes you are right but in case of flash one instance can open multiple file or let it open single file if you close that file thought flash is still remain open.

Comment: Are you kidding? First you ask about notepad, no you edited to question to flash?!?

Comment: No I do not want to detect file change like it is Changed , Created, Deleted I just want to check that on the myfile.fla is close from flash instance or not

Comment: ops sorry I actually wanted flash.

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: This answer was written before the user changed his question from Notepad to Flash. *sigh*)

---

Since Notepad does not support automation, there is no "officially supported" way to do that.

You *might* be able to derive some hack, for example,

- by continuously checking notepad's application title or
- by checking whether there is still some lock on the file (*if* Notepad locks the file in some way, which I don't know).

Still, the solution would likely be quite ugly and require Windows API calls. Maybe if you elaborate on what exact problem you are trying to solve, an alternative solution could be suggested.

Comment: sound nice Boost some thought continuously checking application title and if way application lock file. If you know more about this please ping me the link

Comment: Hey I am checking the application title but its work some time some time it doesn't work what should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can keep watch on the windows title using following code

public static void Main ( )
    {
        IntPtr hwnd = UnsafeNativeMethods.FindWindow("Notepad", null);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(256);
        UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(hwnd, stringBuilder, stringBuilder.Capacity);
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int GetWindowText ( IntPtr hWnd, [Out] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount );
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr FindWindow ( string lpClassName, string lpWindowName );

}